# How are the the singular values & eigenvalues of A and PAP^T related? P is a permutation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations, svd

1. Singular values of $A$ and $PAP^T$: Suppose $A=U\Sigma V^T$. Then $PA=(PU)\Sigma V^T$ so $PA$ and $A$ have the same singular values. Similarly, $A$ and $AP$ have the same singular values. The same reasoning can be applied to $A$ and $PAP^T = (PU)\Sigma (PV)^T$. Is this reasoning correct?
2. Eigenvalues of $A$ and $PAP^T$: Suppose $Ax=\lambda x$. Then, $PAx=\lambda Px$. What about $AP$ and $PAP^T$?

Comment: Hint: What is $P^{-1}$?

Comment: @HansEngler $PAP^Tx= \lambda x \rightarrow P^TPAP^Tx = A(P^Tx) = \lambda (P^Tx) \rightarrow A\hat{x} = \lambda \hat{x}$?

Comment: So now you know that $A$ and $PAP^T$ have the same eigenvalues, and you know how the eigenvectors are transformed. And you also showed that the singular values are unchanged. The underlying reason is that $P$ is an orthogonal matrix.